# How to install python3.6 (dev) on Unbuntu 16.04 without colliding with python3.5 (dev)

Tags: python, ubuntu, cython

I have an app that must be run on `python3.6` and I'd prefer to run it on a Unbuntu 16.04 OS.  Problem is that eventually `python3.6` ends up trolling through `/usr/lib/python3` which is already polluted with `python3.5` libraries.

I've tried uninstalling `python3.5` but packages like `cython3` keep pulling it back in.  I've looked at `pyenv` as well as `update-alternatives`, but I'm not convinced they sanitize the `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include`.  I'm still seeing `python3.6-dev` and `python3.5-dev` conflicts.

Specific repos I'm trying to work on:

- https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum
- https://github.com/trezor/python-trezor

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use `virtualenv`?

Comment: I can add it of things to try, but I didn't see anything that would virtualize `/usr/include` or `/usr/lib` as these are system wide libraries.  I run into trouble when packages trigger source builds that seems not to care so much about pythons environment and focuses more on compiler / library environments system wide.  May be way off base, but that has been my impression

Comment: A virtual environment is (or can be made) independent of all system-wide installs.

Comment: I'll have to look more into it.  I think my big problem is package management.  The `cython` package depends on `python3-dev` which depends on `python3.5`.  I can't build my python app without `cython` and I cant seem to get `cython` to play in a `python3.6` environment.  I suppose I could do a LFS solution and build python3.6, python3.6-dev and cython from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

@tripleee was right, `virtualenv` fixed the problem, but there were quite few bumps along the way.  Here's what I did:

1. Uninstalled cython3: (`apt-get remove cython3`)
2. Installed Py3.6 and dev: (`apt-get install python3.6 python3.6-dev`)
3. Installed VirtualEnv: (`python3.6 -m pip install virtualenv`)
4. Launched VirtualEnv: (`source $HOME/python3.6/bin/activate`)
5. Built and installed `sip-4.19.13` and `PyQt5_gpl-5.11.3` from source.
6. Installed `python-trezor` and `electrum` from source.
7. Launched `electrum` from VirtualEnv

Most of my problems were related to python3-* distribution packages, and the fact that wheels for 32bit linux are getting more and more rare.  This is what predicated the need for me to build `PyQt5` and `sip`.  I had them in a distribution package, but those packages always landed into the 3.5 tree, since 3.6 isn't officially supported on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS yet.

I've included the [`ubuntu16-electrum-git-build.sh`](https://gist.github.com/brianddk/d6d4354938cd571bafa8d2abc023c62a#file-ubuntu16-electrum-git-build-sh) script if anyone is interested.